# Ubuntu 13.4/13.10 shutdown fails

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, shutdown

On both 13.4 (and now after upgrading to 13.10) I find that I can not cycle the machine with a `reboot` because during the shutdown process the step of "Killing all remaining processes" fails:

[image]

I can force a reboot with `reboot -f` that works but I don't want to reboot without the benefit of a graceful shutdown process (which the `-f` imposes). I guess it's also worth stating that the only major software that I've put on top of the base Ubuntu install is:

- mySQL 2.4.6
- Couchbase 2.1.x
- PHP 5.3.x

As you can see from the screenshot it appears that mySQL and Couchbase *have* successfully shutdown and obviously PHP isn't a server process so I'm a little bit unsure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `reboot now` which will drop you into maintenance mode. This is not a bug but can be confusing. If the command doesn't have any explicit option to it, it will drop into maintenance mode. Therefore please use `shutdown -r now` but if you feel this is a bug please comment [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1065851).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1065851

Comment: could it be located anywhere else? I don't have anything at `/var/log/messages`

Comment: try /var/log/syslog - sorry

Comment: ok, the last item in the log is the only mildly suspicious item: `Nov 27 09:56:17 ubuntu rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]`. It's worth noting that I'm using a headless configuration which doesn't use X.

Comment: I have found reference to `/dev/xconsole` in `/etc/rsyslog.d`, also this is an interesting read: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/459730. Am going to remove and see where this leaves me.

Comment: Shoot. Dead end. Was able to remove the xconsole message but it still fails in the "Killing all remaining processes" step. :(

Comment: Try this `shutdown -r now` instead of `reboot`

Comment: yes I was just about to update that I can sort of live with `shutdown -h -r now` (which does seem to work) and actually I now see that even `shutdown -r now` works too. Curiosity is killing me though ... why doesn't `reboot` work and how does it vary from `shutdown -r`?

Comment: @ken I think it's because you are typing `reboot now` which the behavior is "supposed to switch to single-user mode unless an explicit option has been set" I found this information here: 

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1065851

Going to edit my answer.